# Text Changed Event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 3 textfields..
1st)quantity of items..textfield name - tot_qty
2nd)price of item..textfield name - price
3rd)total price..textfield name - tot_price

i want that..
when i enter a particular value in the quantity field and then the price field,the multiplied value should automatically appear in the total quantity field..

i have used the following code

```
protected void tot_price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    tot_price.Text = (float.Parse(tot_qty.Text) *        float.Parse(price.Text)).ToString();
                                                                  }
```

however, after entering value in the total quantity field and then price field and then pressing tab also, nothing happens.

Comment: Do understand that this is a server-side event, it will require a post-back. Might be acceptable here but in general you should look at JavaScript with some js libraries/framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add attribute AutoPostBack="True" to the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tot_price" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

For more information check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tot_qty"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="price" AutoPostBack="True"  OnTextChanged="tot_price_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tot_price"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void tot_price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tot_price.Text = (float.Parse(tot_qty.Text) * float.Parse(price.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: hello, I did try and set the autopostback property of that textfield to true , but to no avail

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the code used, I have just tried it myself. If it is still not working please post your code to check it.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on your `tot_price_TextChanged` method, attach the debugger/press F5, and see if your event is even being hit ?

Comment: Yes, I did and it is has been hit and the value updated successfully. Please share your code with me so we could figure the issue together.

Comment: @FadyWadie I attached the debugger, the event is not being hit.I used the code that you provided ,i dont understand why is the code not working.Can you share your code that ran successfully

Comment: @MrunalPawar I have uploaded the files to google drive at the following link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByZPE-4tiLiLNEduNzBUellMOHM

Answer (score -1):

If you press 'Tab', you could add 'Leave' event (if it's win form app)

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ot_price.Text = (float.Parse(tot_qty.Text) * float.Parse(price.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It's not a WinForms app